# Different PHP script behavior online

Tags: php, date

I have the following problem. I have a script that gets the Airdate of TV Shows and i alter it before I save it to my database. Locally on my localhost it works perfect, but when I tried it online and uploaded it to my web server it shows a different behavior. I have no idea why it is so.

Here are some examples:

---

The Data I get: Aired 1/22/12

What the outcome of my script should be: 2012-01-22

What I get online: 2022/12--

---

The Data I get: Aired 8/29/11

What the outcome of my script should be: 2011-08-29

What I get online: 2029/11--

---

The Data I get: Airs 2/12/12

What the outcome of my script should be: 2012-02-12

What I get online: 2012/12--

---

Here is my PHP script:

```
if(strstr($serie['airdate'], 'Airs')) {
            $date = substr($serie['airdate'], 5);
        }

        if(strstr($serie['airdate'], 'Aired')) {
            $date = substr($serie['airdate'], 6);
        }

        $mm = strstr($date, "/", true);
        $mmStrLen = strlen($mm);
        if((strlen($mm)) == "1") {
            $mm = "0".$mm;
        }

        $dd = substr($date, $mmStrLen+1);
        $dd = strstr($dd, "/", true);
        $ddStrLen = strlen($dd);
        if((strlen($dd)) == "1") {
            $dd = "0".$dd;
        }

        $yy = substr($date, $mmStrLen+1+$ddStrLen+1);
        if((strlen($yy)) == "1") {
            $yy = "0".$yy;
        }

        $serie['date'] = "20".$yy."-".$mm."-".$dd;
```

$serie['airdate'] is the data I get and $serie['date'] is where the altered value should be saved.

The PHP Version I use locally is 5.3.8 and the one of my webhoster is 5.2.17. But I guess this is not the root of the problem.

Comment: Have you verified the data you get in the online version? I know of web services that will use different date formats depending on your machines physical location (via IP).

Comment: I save the original airdate data that I get in the database as well, and it is online exactly the same as offline.. If you meant that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't format a comment as code, so I must write it as an answer.

Please try this on both sides

```
$x=explode(' ',$serie['airdate']);
if (sizeof($x)!=2) die("Error in step 1");
$x=explode('/',$x[1]);
if (sizeof($x)!=3) die("Error in step 2");
$serie['date']=sprintf("20%02d-%02d-%02d",$x[2],$x[0],$x[1]);
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to work on both sides!! Thank you very, very much!!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the raw date string you are splitting locally vs at the server. I'm willing to bet that the OS date format is different locally than on the server, and your string splitting code is not designed to handle the different format the server is using.

Comment: AFAICS he is not using date functions

Comment: All we see is `$serie['airdate']`. How do we know where it's coming from? It could be coming from an RSS feed, or a database that formats the information differently.

Comment: An ajax script gets it from a different website. The content is always a simple string like "Aired 8/29/11".

Answer (score 1):

Thats an awful lot of code to handle dates. Have tried using the [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function?  You can pair it with the [date()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function to easily reformat dates in PHP.

Comment: This might be better suited as a comment instead of an answer.